# What set would these Lego parts belong with?

Tags: set-identification

What set would these Lego parts belong with?
Whites, light gray, and blacks.
Bag is labled #2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on:

- Light Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip with Center Cut on Top
- Yellow Technic Bush 1/2 Smooth
- Pearl Gold Tile, Modified 1 x 2 Grille with Bottom Groove / Lip
- White Wedge 10 x 3
- Light Bluish Gray Tile, Round 1 x 1
- Black Plate 1 x 8

this should be [75248: Resistance A-Wing Starfighter](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75248-1).